# Finding an example where the sequences $(a_nc_n)$ and $(b_nc_n)$ converges to different values

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

suppose we have sequences $(a_n)$, $b_n=a_{n+1}$, and $(c_n)$ where $c_n\neq 0 \forall n$. Furthermore $(c_n)$ has the property where $\lim_{n\to\infty}(c_n/c_{n+1})=1$.

One can show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = L \iff \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = L$.

Let $x= Lc$ where $L$ is the limit of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, and $c$ is the limit of $(c_n)$. Then

$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nc_n = Lc =x  \iff \lim_{n\to\infty}b_nc_n = Lc =x $

therefore if $(b_nc_n)$ converges, then $(a_nc_n)$ converges to the same limit

However, I'm not sure how it is possible to find an example where $(a_nc_n)$  and $(b_nc_n)$ converges to different values, since $a_n$ and $b_n$ have the same limit, then shouldn't  $(a_nc_n)$  and $(b_nc_n)$ converge to the same value no matter what by the algebraic limit theorem?

Comment: It is not given that $(c_n) $ is convergent.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How can one prove that $(a_kc_k)$ converges then? If we consider $a_k(c_k/c_{k+1})=L\cdot 1$ by the algebraic limit theorem, then $a_kc_k=Lc_{k+1}$. However, this doesn't yield anything useful.

Comment: Are you sure it is $(c_n/c_{n+1}) \to 1$ and not $|c_n/c_{n+1}| \to 1$ ?

Comment: @nicomezi yes, its given that $(c_n/c_{n+1})\to 1$ and not $|c_n/c_{n+1}|\to 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is not correct since you assumed convergence of $(c_n)$ However, your guess is right. $(a_nc_n)$ and $(b_nc_n)$ cannot converge to different limits:

$b_nc_n=a_{n+1}c_n=\frac {a_{n+1}c_{n+1}} {c_{n+1}/c_n} $ which shows that $(a_nc_n)$ and $(b_nc_n)$  cannot have different limits. If either of these sequences converges so does the other, with the same limit.

Comment: I see, this also implies that it is not possible for $(a_nc_n)$ to converge while $(b_nc_n)$ diverges, correct?

Comment: @bruhmoment28 Yes, if one of then converges the other one also converges and the limits are same.